# Is there any connection between a matrix being invertible and being diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, diagonalization

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.

If $A$ is invertible then one of it's eigenvalues is 0.

If $A$ is diagonalizable then it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

- Are these two statements true?
- Is there any connection between them? May I infer one from the other?

Comment: if $A$ is invertible then none of its eienvalues is $0$.

Comment: it is possible to state invertibility in terms of eigenvalues, namely that $0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One does not imply the other.

This matrix is invertible and not diagonalizable:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

This matrix is diagonalizable (in fact it is already a diagonal matrix) but not invertible:

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Not only that: statement (1) is completely false, of course, whereas (2) is true...