# Are all invertible matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inverse, diagonalization

Is every invertible matrix over the complex numbers diagonalizable?

Some relevant facts:

- A $n\times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors
- $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, and so every degree $n$ polynomial has $n$ (not necessarily distinct) roots (including the characteristic polynomial)

Sorry if this question is simple and I'm just not seeing it :)

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Any square matrix over an algebraically closed field is similar to the sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: @Dustan:  With slight elaboration your example would make a good Answer.

Comment: @hardmath I doubt this question isn't a duplicate...

Comment: See the Jordan normal form generalizing Dustan's example.

Comment: This question answers my own, but it's not exactly the same statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107610/is-there-any-connection-between-a-matrix-being-invertible-and-being-diagonalizab?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

@Dustan's comment answered the question already, but I found another answer in Axler's elegant book *Linear Algebra Done Right* which elaborates more on the details.

> Unfortunately not every operator is diagonalizable. This sad state of affairs can arise even on complex vector spaces, as shown by the next example.

In the book, he gives a very simple beautiful example: Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{C}^2)$ defined by $T(w, z)=(z, 0)$ then $T$ is not diagonalizable. This can be seen by showing that the basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ does not span $\mathbf{C}^2$.

Comment: This is  the same example as @Dunstan gives, only with $0$ on the diagonal rather than $1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician that's true, the credit goes for Dustan, I just wrote it out explicitly adding some minor details.